# Prolog predicate that do a wrong use of or ;?

Tags: prolog, logic, declarative

I am having some problem to do a specific operation on a specific list.

I have a list of tokens where a **token** represents a word and I want recognize if 5 contiguous tokens in this list, represents a date having the form: **12 Febbraio 1995** where 12 is the day number, Febbraio is the month (in the Italian language) and 1995 is the year (and between a value and the other is a blank space)

For example the previous date is the following tokens list:

**[t(1, "12"),t(-1, " "), t(2, "Febbraio"), t(-1, " "), t(3, "1995")]**

As you can see a general token have a "functor" t and into it there are two arguments: a number (not necessarily progressive, in some cases I have that this value can be -1) and a string that represent a word.

I have try to implement the following predicate but I am finding a problem:

```
tagga([t(Number1, Day), t(-1, Space1), t(Number3, Month), t(-1, Space2), t(Number4, Year)|ListaToken], [d(Number1, CompositeDateTag)|ListaTokenTaggati) :-

    length(Day, LnDay),
    LnDay =:= 2,
    Day = [Head|Tail],
    char_type(Head, digit),

    Space1 == " ",

    Month == "gennaio"; Month == "febbraio"; Month == "marzo"; Month == "aprile"; Month == "maggio"; Month == "giugno"; Month == "luglio";
    Month == "agosto"; Month == "settembre"; Month == "ottobre"; Month == "novembre"; Month == "dicembre";
    Month == "Gennaio"; Month == "Febbraio"; Month == "Marzo"; Month == "Aprile"; Month == "Maggio"; Month == "Giugno"; Month == "Luglio";
    Month == "Agosto"; Month == "Settembre"; Month == "Ottobre"; Month == "Novembre"; Month == "Dicembre", 
    Space2 == " ",

    length(Year, LnYear),
    LnYear =:= 4,
    NumericString = [Head|Tail],
    char_type(Head, digit),

    append(Day, Space1, UntilSpace1),
    append(UntilSpace1, Month, UntilMonth),
    append(UntilMonth, Space2, UntilSpace2),
    append(UntilSpace2, Year, CompositeDateTag),
    write(CompositeDateTag),


    tagga(ListaToken, ListaTokenTaggati).
```

as you can see my **tagga/2** predicate have as first paramether **five tags that could represent a date** (if the body of the rule is TRUE) and a second parameter that represents a unique specialized token (referring to the previous example this new token will be: **d(1, "12 Febbraio 1995") that have the

So, to create the new specialized token it have to check that some properties are true as:

1) The content of the first general token represents a day: **so it have to be a number composed of 2 digits**

2) The content of the second general token is a white space " "

3) The content of the third general token is the name of a months in Italian language

4) The content of the fourth general token represents a day: so it have to be a number composed of 2 digits

5) The content of the fifth general token represents an year **so it have to be a number composed of 4 digits**

Finally it is created the content of the new specialized data token that is the **CompositeDateTag** variable

**The problem occurs after  that it check if the content of the third general token belongs to the list of the months name**.

to do this I check if the **Month** variable value is gennaio **OR** febbraio **OR** marzo and so on, using the **;** operator as **OR** but now something go wrong, in fact I obtain the following trace:

```
[trace]  ?- tagga([t(1, "12"),t(-1, " "), t(2, "febbraio"), t(-1, " "), t(3, "1995")], NewToken).
   Call: (6) tagga([t(1, [49, 50]), t(-1, [32]), t(2, [102, 101, 98, 98|...]), t(-1, [32]), t(3, [49, 57|...])], _G445) ? creep
   Call: (7) length([49, 50], _G602) ? creep
   Exit: (7) length([49, 50], 2) ? creep
^  Call: (7) 2=:=2 ? creep
^  Exit: (7) 2=:=2 ? creep
   Call: (7) [49, 50]=[_G594|_G595] ? creep
   Exit: (7) [49, 50]=[49, 50] ? creep
   Call: (7) char_type(49, digit) ? creep
   Exit: (7) char_type(49, digit) ? creep
   Call: (7) [32]==[32] ? creep
   Exit: (7) [32]==[32] ? creep
   Call: (7) [102, 101, 98, 98, 114, 97, 105, 111]==[103, 101, 110, 110, 97, 105, 111] ? creep
   Fail: (7) [102, 101, 98, 98, 114, 97, 105, 111]==[103, 101, 110, 110, 97, 105, 111] ? creep
   Call: (7) [102, 101, 98, 98, 114, 97, 105, 111]==[102, 101, 98, 98, 114, 97, 105, 111] ? creep
   Exit: (7) [102, 101, 98, 98, 114, 97, 105, 111]==[102, 101, 98, 98, 114, 97, 105, 111] ? creep
   Exit: (6) tagga([t(1, [49, 50]), t(-1, [32]), t(2, [102, 101, 98, 98|...]), t(-1, [32]), t(3, [49, 57|...])], [d(1, _G592)|_G589]) ? creep
NewToken = [d(1, _G592)|_G589]
```

As you can see seems that find the right match between the passed month string "febbraio" and a value into a month list, infact:

```
   Call: (7) [102, 101, 98, 98, 114, 97, 105, 111]==[102, 101, 98, 98, 114, 97, 105, 111] ? creep
   Exit: (7) [102, 101, 98, 98, 114, 97, 105, 111]==[102, 101, 98, 98, 114, 97, 105, 111] ? creep
```

but then seem that skip over calling again the **tagga/2** predicate without execute the following checks that are in my code, these:

```
    Space2 == " ",

length(Year, LnYear),
LnYear =:= 4,
NumericString = [Head|Tail],
char_type(Head, digit),
```

Why? What is the problem? How can I solve? I think that I can also use a month list and say if the string value is present in the string but now I think that there is some problem with my interpretation of ; meaning.

Comment: what is `{{` ... `}}`?

Comment: I can't tell what {{ ... ; ... }} means (apart library(clpqr)). It's your control structure ?

Comment: nono I have just removed from my code...this was an old version of code...now I have not {{}}

Comment: but you should have parenthesis `( ... ; ... )`. Anyway, `memberchk(Month, ["gennaio","febbraio"...])` it's far better, even for performance.

Comment: please copy and paste the source code **as is** from the working source file. then copy and paste **as is** your call, and the response you get from the Prolog prompt. I think you didn't copy the code, and there's a typo there (there's also a syntax error; the code *as is* couldn't have worked).

Comment: Solved with CapelliC tricks tnx guys ;-)

Comment: @AndreaNobili this is not only to help *you*, but future readers as well. :) You should either (A) explain what was the problem and the solution, or (B) remove this question.

Comment: @Will Ness You are right, so I have posted my final solution of this problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is my final solution to the problem, using the CapelliC idea based on a list:

```prolog
tagga([t(Number1, Day), t(-1, Space1), t(Number3, Month), 
                        t(-1, Space2), t(Number4, Year) | ListaToken], 
      [d(Number1, CompositeDateTag) | ListaTokenTaggati]) :-

    length(Day, LnDay),  (LnDay =:= 1; LnDay =:= 2),
    Day = [Head|Tail],   char_type(Head, digit),

    Space1 == " ",

    member(Month, 
           ["gennaio", "febbraio", "marzo", "aprile", "maggio", "giugno",
            "luglio", "agosto", "settembre", "ottobre", "novembre", "dicembre",
            "Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", 
            "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"]),

    Space2 == " ",

    length(Year, LnYear),  LnYear =:= 4,    

    NumericString = [Head|Tail],  char_type(Head, digit),

    append(Day, Space1, UntilSpace1),
        append(UntilSpace1, Month, UntilMonth),
        append(UntilMonth, Space2, UntilSpace2),
        append(UntilSpace2, Year, CompositeDateTag),

    tagga(ListaToken, ListaTokenTaggati).
```